# Is little-o preserved under integration and derivation of another variable?

Tags: integration, limits, derivatives

Given an integrable function $g:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$, and a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $$f(x,y)=o(x^{-1})\;\;\;\;\;\;\text{when }x\rightarrow\infty,$$

i.e. $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} xf(x,y)=0$ for all $y\in\mathbb{R}$.

Is it true that then $$\int f(x,y)g(y)dy=o(x^{-1})\;\;\;\;\;\;\text{ when 
 }x\rightarrow\infty?$$

We know that $f(x,y)g(y)=o(x^{-1})$ and that $o(x^{-1})+o(x^{-1})=o(x^{-1})$, so intuitively it should go through. But when I try to prove it, I need to interchange the limits and the integral and I am not sure I can do it:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} x\int f(x,y)g(y)dy=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\int xf(x,y)g(y)dy=\int \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x,y)g(y)dy=0$$ and I am not sure about the second equality here.

Same question applies to derivatives. If $f:\mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x,y)=o(x^{-1})$, can we say that $$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y)=o(x^{-1})$$?

Comment: The first conjecture is true given the additional assumption that $f(x,y)=O(x^{-1})$ uniformly, i.e. the big-$O$ constant does not depend on $y$.

Comment: Second conjecture is false; restricting to positive values of x and y take $f(x,y)=\frac {\sin (xy)} {x}$. If you are keen on defining f on the whole of $\mathbb R^{2}$ you can take $f(x,y)=\{sin(xy)\} \{1+x^{2})^{-1/4}\}$, for example.